# cannot recieve data from c# tcp server

Tags: c#, android, python, tcp

i've wrote a simple Tcp server in C#:
(I've replaced some of the code parts in "do some stuff", when it doesn't have anything to do with the server.
now, when I try to contact the server from a python client, or an android client, I get errors such as : "the other party actively refused connection". what am I supposed to do? is the problem in my C# code, or am I probably not contacting it correctly?
thank you.

```
public bool ListenLoop(Int32 port, IPAddress localAddr)
        {
            try
            {
              server = new TcpListener(localAddr, port);

              // Start listening for client requests.
              server.Start();
              // Buffer for reading data
              Byte[] bytes = new Byte[256];
              String data = null;

              // Enter the listening loop. 
              while(true) 
              {
                //Waiting for a connection

                // Perform a blocking call to accept requests. 
                TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();            
                //connected!


                // Get a stream object for reading and writing
                NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
                int i;

                // Loop to receive all the data sent by the client. 
                while((i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length))!=0) 
                {   
                  // Translate data bytes to a ASCII string. 
                  data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, i); 
                  //handling opCodes
                  if(data[0] == '0') //log in
                  {
                      //do some stuff
                      byte[] msg = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(response);
                      // Send back a response.
                      stream.Write(msg, 0, msg.Length);
                      //sent    
                  }
                  else if (data[0] == '1') //download tune names
                  {
                      //do some stuff 
                      byte[] msg = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(response); //response is the names
                      // Send back a response.
                      stream.Write(msg, 0, msg.Length);
                      //sent  
                  }
                  else if (data[0] == '2') //changing choice
                  {
                      //do some stuff
                      byte[] msg = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(response);
                      // Send back a response.
                      stream.Write(msg, 0, msg.Length);
                      //sent   

                  }

                }

                // Shutdown and end connection
                client.Close();
              }
            }
            catch(SocketException)
            {
                return false;
            }

            finally
            {
               // Stop listening for new clients.
               server.Stop();     
            }
         }
```

Comment: It'a a connection problem. Check the server is running and check your firewall to make sure the relevant port is open. Also check you're trying to connect to the correct ip/port as there may be something else running on the same machine which doesn't understand your incoming request.

Comment: if you are listening on the `localhost` address then connections from other hosts will be refused.  are you connecting **from** the same machine?

Comment: Hi, I am connecting from the same machine indeed. The weird thing is, that I coppied my code to a console application, and the server worked perfectly fine, but when I run it in the wpf application, it refuses connections

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that there is no firewall that blocks the incoming connection (as it is TCP)?

Also if your server is in testing, you should write some output to either a log file or even just to console. At least you know what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

server = new TcpListener(localAddr, port);
change to
server = new TcpListener(port);

Comment: Please explain your answer.